# Resizing canvas element in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a JavaScript function that is passed a div tag that contains a canvas. I can locate the canvas and read the size of it but I cannot change the size of the canvas.

```
function ReSizeImage(item, Width, Height) {
    var canvas = item.find("canvas");
    canvas.each(function (i) {
        var CW = $(this).width(); //THIS GETS THE CORRECT VALUE
        $(this).width = Width //THIS DOES NOT WORK;
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## jQuery Canvas Manipulation

There's a slight issue to your code, simple fix!

```
 function ReSizeImage(item, Width, Height) {
 var canvas = item.find("canvas");
 canvas.each(function (i) {
    var CW = $(this).width(); //THIS GETS THE CORRECT VALUE
    $(this)[0].width = Width //THIS DOES NOT WORK;
```

$(this) will be getting you a jQuery object and not a DOM element.

Comment: $(this)[0].width = Width; can also be replaced with $(this).width(Width);

Comment: @Harben, sure i only mentioned it because i thought author accidentally wrote $(this).width = Width insteed of $(this).width(Width) as all code is written with jquery.